# Would range-v3 be suitable for applying a function to certain indices in a vector?

Tags: c++, range-v3

Original vector:

```
std::vector<int> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

vector of indices:

```
std::vector<int> b{1, 3, 4};
```

Multiply by 10 each element in **a** that is indexed by the elements in **b**.
Iterative implementation:

```
for (auto i = 0; i < b.size(); ++i)
    a[b[i]] *= 10;
```

Resulting **a**:

```
1 20 3 40 50 6
```

I wonder if I can apply a *filter* | *transform* composition from range-v3 to accomplish this? Or could this be done with the pre-range standard algorithms?

Comment: Transform `b` instead? `b | ranges::view::transform([&a](int i)-> int& { return a[i]; });`?

Comment: That would indeed filter elements from "a" whose indices are in "b". The question is though how we can get the result that is printed out, i.e. an array containing {1, 20, 3, 40, 50, 6}.

Comment: Then you can `action::transform` the transformed `b` view.

Comment: Slightly odd is that `a[i]` does not necessarily check if `i` is admissible. E.g., `ranges::views::ints(0,10)[100]` works.